# extjs fish eye menu custom event

Tags: extjs

i have created a extjs fish eye menu using the code

```
var fm = new Ext.ux.FisheyeMenu({
    renderTo : 'dataView',
    itemWidth : 60,
           items : [{
                text: 'Map',
         imagePath: 'images/table_48.png',
         url: 'http://maps.google.com'
            }, {
                text: 'Photo',
         imagePath: 'images/table_48.png',
         url: 'http://picasaweb.google.com'
            }]


        });
```

How to add custom listener for the menu. When i click on a menu item i need to get the text of that menu item.
I have tried

```
listeners: {
        click: function () {
```

................
}
but this is not working
How we can do this. Can anybody paste a sample code

Answer (score 0):

There is no click event for Fisheyemenu. The component has `change` event to monitor any click inside the menu container. You need to use:

```
listeners: {
    change : function(menu,targetItem,index) {
     // Your logic according to index or clicked item (targetItem)
    }
}
```

Refer the [docs](http://cz9908.com/blog/Niko-weblog-labs/lab-Niko-Ext-Core-UX-Doc/output/) for more details on this component!

Comment: when i add this listener i am getting the error me.events is undefined